# How does reducing a monster's hit points affect its CR?

Tags: dnd-5e, cr-calculation

The Party needs to recover a stolen chariot filled with goods from a large band of kobolds. However, when they arrive, it turns out that all the kobolds have been killed by three ogres. One ogre is dead and two are alive, but wounded. They therefore have lower health than the printed statblocks. The party needs to engage them to recover the chariot. Should I lower their CR? If so, how can I determine how much to lower it by?

**How does reducing a monster's hit points affect its CR?**

Comment: Hi LupaShiva; welcome to the site! Make sure to take the [tour]. I've made a fairly substantial edit to your question to clarify it, and improve the english somewhat (which was actually very good, I might add). If you don't like my edit, or you think I have changed your meaning, feel free to roll the edit back.

Answer (score 4):

Turn to page 273 of your Dungeon Master's Guide. There, you will find all the information you need to adjust a creature's CR based on its damage per round, attack bonus, armour class, and hit points.

You will discover in the process that, using the given system, the CR for the standard ogre (as printed) should be 1. The reason they increased it to 2 is because an ogre can kill a first level character in a single round. For more information on this, look at [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/69206/ogre-cr-calculation-is-it-wrong-or-am-i-missing-something). As a result, unless you have decreased the health hugely, I don't recommend that you reduce the ogres' CR below 1.

Even with lower hit points, the ogres' attacks will still hurt a lot. You might therefore want to be careful, particularly if your party is only first level. Some of those attacks will be able to knock the squishier characters unconscious in a single round of combat.

Comment: Thank you a lot, awesome help, already checked and i though that section on the DM was only for creating NPCs, i think ill lower for CR 1.

Comment: @LupaShiva Glad I could be of assistance. If you feel that your problem is solved, consider 'accepting' this answer (the tick symbol) to let other people know that you are not in immediate need of another answer (although they may still provide one if they feel they can add something).